# How to setup Environment variables for different environments while consuming API

Tags: c#, api

What would be the best approach to configure environment variables in a c# application.

In my application I will be consuming an API by using HhtpWebRequest

```
            var url = "API Endpoint";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            try
            {
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                {
                    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();   
                    
                    
                }
            }
```

The url will be different for different environments like we have QA and Prod.

What will be the best way to configure these endpoints, so the application will pick the endpoint based on the environment.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: utilize the appSettings.json and environment variables

Comment: Could you please provide me with an example